# Addition of matching array key params in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array, in this array there are same dates for key 112.
I need addition of those arrays whose dates are same.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-02-17
        [97] => 20.00
        [84] => 13.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-02-17
        [97] => -5
        [84] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-02-17
        [97] => -5
        [84] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-03-17
        [97] => 10
        [84] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-03-17
        [97] => -5
        [84] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-03-17
        [97] => -5
        [84] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-01-17
        [97] => 2
        [84] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-01-17
        [97] => 13
        [84] => 0
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-01-17
        [97] => 2
        [84] => 0
    )
)
```

For example from above array I need following result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-02-17
        [97] => 10.00
        [84] => 13.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-03-17
        [97] => 0
        [84] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [112] => 2015-01-17
        [97] => 17
        [84] => 0
    )
)
```

In this resultant array I need addition of those array whose 112 key value that is date is same.

I have thousands of records like this.  So please suggest simple and fastest way.  Also I need to preserve keys of all the inner arrays.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the original structure?

Comment: Yes...Same like resultant array that i have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `foreach` loop and iterate each element in array.

```
$array = array(
  array(
    112 => '2015-02-17',
    97 => 20,
    84 => 13
  ),
  array(
    112 => '2015-02-17',
    97 => -5,
    84 => 13
  ),
  array(
    112 => '2015-02-17',
    97 => -5,
    84 => 13
  ),
  array(
    112 => '2015-02-18',
    97 => 10,
    84 => 13
  ),
  array(
    112 => '2015-02-18',
    97 => 10,
    84 => 13
  ),
);


$result = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
  if (isset($result[$item[112]])) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
      if ($key != 112) { # we don't need to sum 'date column' 
        if (isset($result[$item[112]][$key])) {
          $result[$item[112]][$key] += $value;
        } else {
          $result[$item[112]][$key] = $value;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    $result[$item[112]] = $item;
  }
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would manipulate the array so the value of the 112 key was the key of the new array and the value was a list of each item in the original that matches the 112 value.  Then iterate over it checking if there is more than 1 item in the array, and if so sum them.  ie

```
$data = array(...); // all your source data
$matches = array();
$results = array();

// reformat data into an associative array
foreach($data as $item) {
    if(!array_key_exists($item[112], $matches)} { 
        $matches[$item[112]] = array();
    }
    $matches[$item[112]][] = $item;
}

foreach($matches as $items) {
    if(count($items) == 1)
        continue; // if we don't have at least 2 matching 112's, skip
    $sum = array();
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        // iterate over each key, and add it to the array
        foreach($item as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == 112)
                $sum[$key] = $value; // assign 112, don't add it again

            if(array_key_exists($key, $sum))
                $sum[$key] += $value;
            else
                $sum[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $results[] = $sum; // add sum to list of sum'ed items
}
// $results now contains any matches sum'ed together
```

I didn't test, but should work

Comment: Updated my original answer, noticed some typos